# Is it possible to maintain a persistent SQL connection to a postgres database?

Tags: python-polars

With Pandas, we are able to create persistent connections, which allows (for example) creating temporary tables against which we can join. For example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine("postgresql://me@server:port/my_db")

# create a temporary table
sql = """
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE my_table (
  name varchar(50),
  age SMALLINT,
  birth_date DATE
);
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('me', 38, '1980-01-01');
"""

conn.execute(sql)

# now perform a SELECT using the persistent connection
df = pd.read_sql_table("my_table", conn)
```

However, polars appears to use a string as a connection, and presumably creates a new connection with each query. Is there a way to use polars along with persistent connections?

Answer (score 0):

Polars uses [ConnectorX](https://github.com/sfu-db/connector-x) in `read_sql`, which is a really thin and convenient wrapper around `pl.from_arrow(cx.read_sql(connection_uri, sql,...))`. Polars uses Arrow as the underlying data structure, meaning that `pl.from_arrow` is (mostly) zero-copy and efficient. Thus any python SQL query package that returns an Arrow table would work. An example would be [TurbODBC](https://turbodbc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/advanced_usage.html#apache-arrow-support), but there may be more that return an Arrow table and maintain a persistent connection.